# How To Install Zoiper

Tags: software-installation, voip

I'm a Linux Novice.

I'm trying to figure out how to install Zoiper on Ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded it and extracted it to my Downloads folder. Then, I followed this instruction:

```
sudo ./Zoiper_3.3_Linux_Free_64Bit.run
```

Then the terminal says

```
sudo ./Zoiper_3.3_Linux_Free_64Bit.run
```

If I type in the terminal:

```
sudo /home/xarcell/Downloads/Zoiper_3.3_Linux_Free_64Bit.run
```

it then throws a warning that is not root?

That is indeed the file name. What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The file may download to the `/tmp/zarcell0` folder, or Downloads.

From your download (let's say in Firefox) click on the whole line and choose 'Open Containing Folder'.
There, right click on the Zoiper download, go down and click on 'Extract Here'.
Open that folder, and choose either the 32 or 64bit run file. 
Right click on the file you need, copy.

Open File Manager and go to Downloads. Paste it there.

Open the Terminal. Type this in:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo chmod +x Zoiper_3.3_Linux_Free_64Bit.run
sudo ./Zoiper_3.3_Linux_Free_64Bit.run
```